# Formula for Standardized Estimates in SEM

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

In trying to interpret my output from a Confirmatory Factor Analysis, I find myself pondering the relationship between the standardized and unstandardized factor loadings. Is there a formula in terms of the unstandardized estimates and the various standard deviations or variances that will yield the standardized estimates? I can't find it anywhere. (I'm using EQS 6.1, if it matters).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Further searching finds an answer from David A. Kenny (http://davidakenny.net/cm/1factor.htm), that seems to work:

"Conversion from the Unstandardized to the Standardized Solution:
       loading: multiply the loading by standard deviation of the latent variable divided by the standard deviation of the indicator
      error path: square root of one minus the standardized loading squared "